# dual boot Win 10 Fedora 29 - failed to set new efi boot target - kernel or firmware bug

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, fedora, thinkpad

My Lenovo Thinkpad 13 came with Win 10 preinstalled. I would like to use Fedora 29 on it as well but keep Win 10 as I use some software that does not have a linux versions.

I created live Fedora with Rufus, assigned a space on the disk and proceeded with dual boot install.

Only at the end of the installation process I received this message:

> The following error occurred while installing the boot loader. The system will not be bootable. Would you like to ignore this and continue with installation?
>
> **Failed to set new efi boot target. This is mostly likely a kernel or firmware bug.**`

I need to point out that:

- Secure boot was disabled
- A dual boot from Win 8 to Fedora 29 on my older but not so old and UEFI Toshiba Satellite works fine...

Comment: A few possibilities: When building in Rufus, select the option for *both* BIOS and EFI. Also, though secure boot is not recommended if using certain packages, I find that Ubuntu installs with secure boot enabled. BTW, some Windows programs, such as 7-Zip & IrfanView, run well under wine... but others don't, so dual boot might still be needed..

Comment: thnx for a quick reaction! I double checked rufus. the target system is **BIOS or UEFI**

Comment: meaning I still struggle...